# Multiline regex from single long string

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

This is in Powershell 7.x, but I believe it is a general regex question.

I have the headers from an email in one long string, and would like to capture them with the Powershell split function using a regex to get what I need.

Looks like this:

```
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-InternalOrgSender: False
Received: from YQBPR0101CA0152.CANPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10b6:c01:e::25)
 by YQBPR0101MB5927.CANPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10b6:c01:36::19) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.6652.27; Tue, 8 Aug
 2023 03:59:56 +0000
Received: from YQBCAN01FT026.eop-CAN01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10b6:c01:e:cafe::70) by YQBPR0101CA0152.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10b6:c01:e::25) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.6652.27 via Frontend
 Transport; Tue, 8 Aug 2023 03:59:56 +0000
```

So I want every line that starts with a word character '(?m)(^\w+)' gets that for me. But I also want everything after that up till the next ^\w+. Every extra line I want to capture with the \w+ starts with white space followed by non white space. I am thinking one of the lookarounds may be of use here, but I can't seem to get it. Any ideas?

Two regexex that failed for me:

```
'(?sm)(^\w.*(\n\s+.*)+)'
'(?m)(^\w.*(?=(\n\s+.*)*))'
```

Comment: The pattern should look like `(?m)^\w.*(?:\n[\s-[\n]].*)*`

Comment: My bad, forgot to say I want to capture the whole matching string, multi line or not. So I ended up with (?m)(^\w.*(?:\n[\s-[\n]].*)*) Thank you Wiktor.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. So that others may benefit from it too, please consider posting it as an answer, ideally with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?m)^(\w.*(?:\n[\s-[\n]].*)*)
```

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier
- `^` - start of any line
- `(\w.*(?:\n[\s-[\n]].*)*)` - capturing group #1:

  - `\w.*` - a word char and then any zero or more chars other than a line feed char as many as possible
  - `(?:\n[\s-[\n]].*)*` - zero or more repetitions of a line feed char, then any whitespace other than a line feed and then any zero or more chars other than a line feed char as many as possible.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wGpE9g/1).